# Installing Qt 6 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, software-installation, qt

I need to install Qt 6 development files to build a third-party application in CentOS 7. I have been informed that the following packages are required on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS:

- qt6-base-dev
- qt6-tools-dev
- qt6-tools-dev-tools
- libqt6svg6-dev

I checked CentOS 7 package repositories, and I couldn't find any package for Qt in these repositories. Is there any guideline to install Qt 6 in CentOS 7?

Comment: Let's face it: you would have to build all of qt6 from source and would lose all advantage of having a stable distro. So. Don't do that, run your qt6 application in a container that contained a less ancient userland then CentOS 7

Comment: C7 was released over 9 years ago. The last full updates came from over 3 years ago. I would advise you to update to a more recent o/s. Installing packages from another distro is just going to cause you problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build QT6 on CentOS 7 from source, you need `gcc` v10 toolset from third party repository and `cmake` 3.16 or newer. See [Building from Source](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linux-building.html).

A snap is available [`kde-qt6-sdk`](https://snapcraft.io/kde-qt6-sdk) it can be [installed through](https://snapcraft.io/install/kde-qt6-sdk/centos):

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install snapd
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
sudo snap install kde-qt6-sdk
```